# Releasing objects in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I just need some help regarding memory management. I'm displaying around 500 frames on the screen. My app seems to be running fine on the simulator but on the iPad it crashes after displaying around 450 frames. The problem seems to be coming due to insufficient memory. Below is a part of my code. Am I releasing the objects correctly or is there something more that I need to do?

```
- (void)drawBufferWidth:(int)width height:(int)height pixels:(unsigned char*)pixels
{
     CGRect rect = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 0.0, 0.0);
     UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
     CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
     CGContextRef gtx = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, BitsPerComponent, BytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
     CGImageRef myimage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(gtx); 
     img.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:myimage];

     CGContextRelease(gtx);
     CGImageRelease(myimage);
     CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

Comment: are you using ARC or not?

Comment: Press control + f to find alloc...your img is alloc but never release

Comment: Using the Analyze tool would really help you with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method appears to be leaking the `UIImageView` you are creating on the second line.  You have an `alloc` with no corresponding `release` or `autorelease`.  I say "appears" because I suspect you haven't included all of the method (you don't show us any code that does anything with your UIImageView...).

Your management of the various CGRefs is fine.

Comment: Oh alright.. Which of the following do I need to do? UIImageView *img = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect] autorelease]; OR [img release];

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to give a precise answer, but `autorelease` is the safer answer.

Comment: I'd lean to -release myself.  Actually, a better answer would be to migrate to ARC and let the compiler deal with it automatically.

Comment: @bbum Without seeing what the OP's doing with the UIImageView, I'm reticent to tell him to just `release` it.  But agreed that everyone should be moving to ARC by now.